# PowerShell 'Or' Statement

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to go through the Active Directory, and grab users who meet a certain criteria. I want to get users have either Manager A or Manager B, but I'm not sure how to implement the or statement. Here's my code:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties country, extensionattribute9 | if (extensionattribute9 -eq 'Smith, Joe') or (extensionattribute9 -eq 'Doe, John') {select extensionsattribute9, country}
```

In this code, it doesn't recognize `extensionattribute9`, which gives you the user's manager.

I also tried attempted using `where` instead of `if`, but to no avail.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The operator is `-or`, not `or`. See [`about_Logical_Operators`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847789.aspx). Also, `if` statements don't read from the pipeline. Either put the `if` statement in a `ForEach-Object` loop:

```
... | ForEach-Object {
  if ($_.extensionattribute9 -eq 'Smith, Joe' -or $_.extensionattribute9 -eq 'Doe, John') {
    $_ | select extensionsattribute9, country
  }
}
```

or use a `Where-Object` statement instead:

```
... | Where-Object {
  $_.extensionattribute9 -eq 'Smith, Joe' -or
  $_.extensionattribute9 -eq 'Doe, John'
 } | Select-Object extensionsattribute9, country
```

And you can't use property names by themselves. Use the [current object variable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx) (`$_`) to access properties of the current object.

For checking if an attribute has one of a given number of values you can also use the `-contains` operator instead of doing multiple comparisons:

```
'Smith, Joe', 'Doe, John' -contains $_.extensionattribute9
```

Comment: -or still gives me the error that extensionattribute9 is not recognized.